# Attempting to populate a dropdownlist through LINQ to entities in C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am attempting to populate a DropDownlist but it does not seem to be populating and I am not sure why it isnt. Could I get a second pair of eyes to help me figure out where I am gowing wrong?
 Below is my code:

```
    private testhousingEntities1 canceldb = new testhousingEntities1();
   /*=================================================*/  
   /*load form                                        */
   /*=================================================*/  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            InitializeForm();
        }        
    }

    /*================================================*/ 
    /*                                                */
    /*================================================*/  
    private void InitializeForm()
    {
        var version = (from v in canceldb.CancellationVersions
                       where v.Active
                       select v).FirstOrDefault();  

       /*populating states and countries drop downlist */
        FormHelpers.GenerateStates(ddlState);
        FormHelpers.GenerateCountries(ddlCountry);

        /*populating  drop downlist */
        semesterList();            
    }

    /*=================================================*/
    /*populating the Semester drop downlist            */
    /*=================================================*/  
    private void semesterList()
    {
        ddlSemester.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---------", "000"));

        var semester = from s in canceldb.cancellationsemesters
                       select new {                                
                                    cid= s.id, cSemester = s.Semester,                           
                                  };
        ddlSemester.DataSource = semester;
        ddlSemester.DataTextField = "cSemester";
        ddlSemester.DataValueField = "cid";
        ddlSemester.DataBind();
    }

    /*=================================================*/  
    /*populating the Semester drop downlist            */
    /*=================================================*/  
    protected void ddlSemester_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {              
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           semesterList();                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a ToList();

```
ddlSemester.DataSource = semester.ToList();
```

Comment: That didnt do anything. It took out the "-----" i had as the first item in the list actually. But the list is still empty

Comment: Try to break this out into a class.
{cid= s.id, cSemester = s.Semester}
It might not like binding to the anonymous class.

Comment: Anonymous objects are correct in this scenario. See e.g. http://brandonatkinson.blogspot.cz/2011/03/populating-aspnet-dropdownlist-control.html

Comment: This did not make a change. Im not sure